Progress report on June 2012 goal
As you are probably familiar, we have a short term goal for June:
Short term goal for June 2012: More than 2.5 questions per day
We need to achieve 75 questions this month in order to meet the goal. That means around 25 questions in the first 10 days. Here is our number of questions asked in the first ten days:
2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6, 3, 2
For a total of 30 questions. We are doing great, right now we are even matching our initial dream of 3 questions a day. However, it is mostly fueled by that 6 question day on the 8th. Let's keep up the pace.

Remind your friends and colleagues to ask questions during this month! And a question for you:
Is there anything more we can do to promote good question asking?

3.1 questions/day on Area 51  as per 15th June;

3.4 questions/day on Area 51 as per 20th June

3.6 questions/day on Area 51 as per 27th June

And we've added 5 more 200+ rep users!

And 1 more 3000+ rep user :-)  Congrats @Artem

And a 5K user! @JeromyAnglim

I think a good way for us to promote good question asking would be to gather up some question exemplars (by votes is a decent first approximation, then we can filter from there), and have a Meta question which has the text of each exemplar as a separate answer.
We could make up "ideal" questions, but I think the bodies of actual questions would be better.  Users might not be willing to hunt down questions to read on their own, but having them in a central location might bring some readers.
We could then direct users to that post to read some good questions, or potentially link to that Meta post in a system message if it was as unobtrusive as possible.

I really like this suggestion. I think we should have a thread like the self-evaluation except instead of random questions we try to gather some good (but maybe not top-voted) questions that cover the breadth of the site.

Artem, I really liked your idea of seeking personal targets for question asking amongst active users. Active users are also more likely to ask quality questions. Some of the questions we get from casual users are not very scientific; I think when these questions are interspersed with high quality questions, it's less problematic for the overall feel of the site.
I'm also looking forward to when we hit the "okay" range on number of avid users; I'm not sure exactly what the target is, but it's more than 70 and less than 89.

So by extension to Jeromy's observation about avid users, please don't hesitate to vote for quality content (and downvote poor content).  Primarily, it helps future readers of the site know about good content, but it also rewards your fellow users and helps build the site. Please see Vote early, vote often for details.

Here are our questions per day for the month, each line is a week. Starting on June 1 and going until end of June 27 (UTC time):
_, _, _, _, _, 2, 3
2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6, 3
2, 2, 1, 4, 7, 3, 3,
1, 4, 2, 5, 1, 3, 3,
1, 6, 7, 2
Thus, we have asked a total of 85 questions so far in June; that is an average of 3.15 per day! We surpassed our goal of 75 and have 3 days to ask 5 more questions and pass the more ambitious goal of 90. Here is a snapshot of our stats upto June 28th:

Good job, everybody!
